# If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is an harmonic function, the second partial derivatives are zero at a local maximum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know this question has been asked before but the answers given are not clear to me. I tried to prove this as my own but I conclude exactly the opposite. If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is an harmonic function, that is

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=0$$. And if $(x_{0},y_{0}) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a strict local maximum of $f$, then the second partial derivatives are zero at such point.

Relaxing the notation $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=f_{xx}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=f_{yy}$. Then, the local maximum and minimum test says that $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is local maximum if $f_{xx}(x_{0},y_{0})<0$ and $$[f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2](x_{0},y_{0})>0.$$ But $f_{xx}(x_{0},y_{0})<0$ and having  $f_{xx}=-f_{yy}$, implies that $f_{yy}(x_{0},y_{0})>0$. So neither of the second partial derivatives are zero.

Could anyone  please explain me a detailed proof of this problem?

Comment: I like that you wrote a**n** harmonic function

Comment: harmonic functions obey the maximum/minimum principle - the 2-sided real analog of maximum modulus for holomorphic functions - (by the mean value property) so do not have extrema inside their domain (in particular if the domain is the plane, do not have extrema at all) unless they are constant

Comment: @Conrad It seems likely the OP has not yet encountered the MP.

Comment: I think you're using the local extrema test in reverse, and this is not allowed. That is, a local max does not imply $\det Hf < 0$, (consider $x^{4}$ in 1D) but $\det Hf <0$ would imply that the critical point is a max.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $f$ has a local max at $(a,b).$ Then $f_x(a,b)=0.$ Suppose $f_{xx}(a,b) > 0.$ Go back to one variable to see $x\to f(x,b)$ has a strict local min at $x=a,$ contradiction.

Comment: But we are addding an extra hypothesis saying $f$ has local max at $0$. I mean, what if there is not local max at $0$ ?? @zhw

Comment: @Cos It's a hint. $0$ was chosen for convenience. Try to use the idea for any local max. (I edited my answer.)

Comment: OK, I understand the fact you are bulding a proof by contradiction.Thanks for the last edit. Also what if $f_{xx}(a,b)<0$ or $f_{xx}(a,b)=0$?? :/ @zhw

Comment: @Cos Well, we haven't used $\Delta f (a,b)=0$ yet ...

Comment: I meant the contradiction arises from the supposition of $f_{xx}(a,b)>0$ or $f_{xx}(a,b)<0$. Lets suppose $f_{xx}(a,b)>0$ as you stated, now if we want go to a single variable we can fix $b$ or $a$, you fixed $b$ right? But I still dont understand your last two steps "$x\to f(x,b)$ has a strict local min at $x=a,$ contradiction" I would aprecciate if you can be more explicit over these. @zhw

Comment: I got that because our assumption of $(a,b)$ local maximum of $f$, then $\nabla f (a,b)=f_{x}(a,b)i+f_{y}(a,b)j=0+0=0$. But Im not sure how to use this fact @zhw

Comment: @Cos  Lemma: Suppose in one variable $g'(a)=0, g''(a)>0.$ Then $g$ has a strict local min. at $a.$ Try to prove this.